# Error on activating/upgrading a site template

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template, feature-activation, wspbuilder

A site template of site collection-X was used to create a subsite on site collection-Y, both are on SharePoint Online. I was thrown errors that a list of features were Not Activated/Not Licensed. I can activate the ones that are not activated with SharePoint Online Management Shell. But am not sure of licensing the missing features (would be great if advised how to?) So I went a head to modify the site template and redeploy(upload the .wsp file to solutions Gallery) to the target site.

Process followed is, 1) rename the .wsp(site template) file to .cab 2) Extract with iZArc tool to a folder. 3) Made changes to ONet.xml and removed the features that were Not Activated/Not Licensed. 4) After the changes generate a .cab file of the folder with iZArc tool. 5) Rename the .cab file to .wsp 6) Upload it back to the Solutions gallery.

When trying to activate the solution, an error is thrown saying files are missing and cannot activate the site template.